# gridview column cell background-color depend on cell value

Tags: asp.net, gridview, text, conditional-statements

I have a function and asp.net; please see the comment in first function as the question.

Or if my method is not good, please share your ideas. am new to asp.net. =)

```
protected String DelayedText(object base__id_with_time, object file_name_with_time)
{
   DateTime _dateTime1= Convert.ToDateTime(base__id_with_time);
   DateTime _dateTime2= DateTime.ParseExact(file_name_with_time, "dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   int timeDifference = DateTime.Compare(_dateTime1 , _dateTime2);
   if (timeDifference >= 1)
   {
       //how to set that certain gridview cell's background color to red here please? 
   }
   return timeDifference.ToString();
}


<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delayed" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="DelayedCheck" runat="server" Text='<%# DelayedDeliveryText(Eval("CreateDate"),Eval("FileName"))%>' 
          />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you =)

Comment: Can't you do it in the RowDataBound event? If you have the condition there then it is just e.Row.Cells[yourCellIndex].BackColor = Color.Red;

Comment: @jannagy02 could you be more specific please? also, there are also rows that I want to skip. for example, if that row's name has string "abc". then i just want to skip to next row. but in that case, Ｉneed to pass the database content in again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution. According to your code : Let Gridview name is "grvData"

```
//how to set that certain gridview cell's background color to red here please?
 foreach (GridViewRow row in grvData.Rows)
 {
      Label lblDelayedCheck= ((Label)row.FindControl("DelayedCheck")).Text;
      lblDelayedCheck.Cells[CellIndexNo].BackColor = Color.Red; 
 }
```